# Python CTRL+C to exit interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, interpreter

Python 2.73

Why is it on my laptop when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I can exit the interpreter and on my desktop hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will make the interpreter shoot back at me a KeyboardInterrupt message. How can I get rid of this KeyboardInterrupt and go back to exiting with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>!

On my desktop it's required to input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and hitting enter to exit.

I am using PowerShell on both computer. Same 64bit, one is Win7 one is Win8

Comment: Are you using the same shell on both machines?

Comment: Because your laptop is running something different from your desktop.

Comment: Can it possibly be versions of windows? Both using Powershell 64 as admin

Comment: What does `signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)` return? It should return `<built-in function default_int_handler>`; if it doesn't then there is something that is removing the default handler and doesn't raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: On Ubuntu you use ctrl-d to logout of a program, but that's not limited to python but general functionality.

Comment: you may quit python interpreter by typing `quit()`

Comment: Curious to know if you have .pythonstartup.py files on either machine and if their contents are different.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the signal handler for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to something that exits the interpreter:

```
import signal
import sys
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda number, frame: sys.exit())
```

You could probably put that code in a file to be run automatically when an interactive session starts, then set the environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP to the name of that file:

http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=startup#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter version of the previous answer:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

`SIG_DFL` means default signal handling, so Python does not catch it to
raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.