# Windows Python interpreter exits on Ctrl+C

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

With most Python interpreters that I've used, Ctrl+C will cause the interpreter to print out "`KeyboardInterrupt`" and remain open. However, in a recent install on a new computer, Ctrl+C is causing the interpreter to exit, which is undesirable.

- Setting the `signal.SIGINT` handler still exits.
- There isn't a startup script being run that could adjust behaviour.
- `raise KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't exit the interpreter.
- No text is emitted on Ctrl+C. On Ctrl+Break, `^C` is emitted before exit.

If I Ctrl+C during the snooze in the following snippet, the interpreter remains open.

```
import time

try:
    time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Environment: Python 3.4.3 on Windows 10

Comment: are you by chance running python under MSYS or another unix commands terminal?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, nope.  I use ConEmu but get the same behaviour in both cmd and powershell.

Comment: on my computer CTRL+Pause emits a "^C" and exits python. Ctrl+C issues keyboard interrupt all right.

Comment: If I handle a KeyboardInterrupt the interpreter will remain open (see edit) if that means anything.

Comment: opposite request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707523/python-ctrlc-to-exit-interpreter

Comment: @eryksun, yep.  Upgrading to 3.6 fixed the problem.

Comment: @eryksun, do you want to create an answer so I can mark this as answered?  Or wat do?  This is my first rodeo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl+C handling is broken at the shell prompt for Python versions prior to 3.6 when run on Windows 8 and above. It's also broken for `input` and `raw_input`, for which you'll get an `EOFError` instead of a `KeyboardInterrupt`. You can fix this by installing and enabling `win_unicode_console` -- or by upgrading to 3.6

The problem is that Python's old code for reading from the console depends on `ReadFile` setting the last error to `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` (995) when reading is interrupted by Ctrl+C. In Windows 8, Microsoft completely rewrote how client processes talk to the console. In so doing they broke the documented contract for the behavior of `ReadFile` in this case. Without the error, Python thinks the aborted read was a successful read of 0 bytes. Normally this indicates end of file (`EOF`), so the REPL simply quits as if the user had typed Ctrl+Z, Enter.

`ReadFile` is a generic read from any File handle. There is also a specialized `ReadConsole` function. This one still behaves correctly, which is why `win_unicode_console` and 3.6+ don't have this problem. They call `ReadConsoleW` to solve the separate problem of using the full range of Unicode in the console, and this just happens to also solve the Ctrl+C problem.

---

FYI, the `^C` that you see on the screen isn't written by the console (conhost.exe) or Python. It's actually printed by the `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` handler that's set by the cmd.exe shell. If you run Python from PowerShell, you shouldn't see this printed with Ctrl+Break.